# join spark dataframes rows order

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I am playing with spark dataframes joining and I notice that when using join with dataframes API the order of rows changes. 
Below is the example I am working on :

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 1.0, 0.4, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.9, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.9, 0.2, 0.2)))
                               .toDF("id2", "prop1", "prop2", "prop3")

val df2 = sc.parallelize(Array((0, 3.0, 0.2, 0.1),
                               (1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.3),
                               (2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2),
                               (3, 0.8, 0.1, 0.1),
                               (4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5)))
                               .toDF("id", "prop1_2", "prop2_2", "prop3_2")
val joined = df2.join(df, df("id2")===df2("id"), "outer")



joined.show()

id|prop1_2|prop2_2|prop3_2| id2|prop1|prop2|prop3|
+---+-------+-------+-------+----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|    0.9|    0.3|    0.3|   1|  0.9|  0.3|  0.3|
|  3|    0.8|    0.1|    0.1|   3|  0.9|  0.2|  0.2|
|  4|    0.3|    0.5|    0.5|null| null| null| null|
|  2|    0.2|    0.5|    0.2|   2|  0.2|  0.9|  0.2|
|  0|    3.0|    0.2|    0.1|   0|  1.0|  0.4|  0.1|
```

May you please give me any tricks to avoid this. 
I am not sure if I use datasets API instead of dataframes API  I can avoid this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It is a feature, not an issue. In general non local operations in Spark (also known as wide transformations if you are familiar with the original RDD paper) don't guarantee any specific order of processing.

Furthermore, when using `Dataset` / SQL API, the same logical plan can be executed in different ways depending on:

- Configuration.
- Runtime statistics.
- Injected optimizer rules.

and so on. If specific order is required it should be always enforced explicitly with `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

you cant maintain order with join, but it seems you should just sort by id after the join, if the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid this behavior.

This is named : shuffle

spark redistribute the data across the cluster.

many operation can trigger shuffle: join, groupBy, cogroup...

see: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations